# Preference Activity store/load values from custom source

Tags: android, storage, preferenceactivity

I am building an app which allows the user to define multiple objects of a specific type, lets call them "Person"'s. The "Person" object is defined as such:

```
class Person {
  public String name;
  public int age;
}
```

These "Person" objects will be serialised and stored within the app, either in SharedPreferences or via a Cloud storage mechanism. This can be considered handled and working.

My problem is that I need an editor interface to allow the user to change the "name" and "age" of any particular "Person" instance in their collection. In order to make my UI feel as much like stock as possible, I would like my editor interface to resemble the "Preference" interface which Android implements. As such I need a way to make a "PreferenceActivity" load and save it's preferences from/to a POJO.

The reason I am looking to do this is so that I have a UI that feels like something the user is used to using. My other choice is to mimic the style and create all the handling code myself, which will take a lot of time.

I imagined the process would be to override the "load" and "save" functions of a "PreferenceActivity" to pull/push the values from a POJO provided "onCreate" via an "Intent" - and the return this POJO as an activity result to the caller.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of having it this way? I fail to see why this would be useful nor how it would be feasible with regards to the reference of the pojo containing the data. If it was possible then the saving object would most likely be a generic key-object map, where you would need to extract the data from, which is exactly how the Preferences already work.

If the point of this is just to have the information in a Person object why not just make a method that creates one based on the saved preferences.

----- Additions

If you add a static/singleton data handler(repository) in the App that will contain all the persons while the App is executing, and that it has some kind of identifier for each person. Then you can pass the ID in the intent to the PreferenceActivity which will in turn fetch the person object from the data handler and fill in the values of the PreferenceActivity based on it.

Add another Preference to the PreferenceActivity named "Save" or similar, which you resolve and bind in the activity. When clicked this will fetch the currently entered information (which will be saved in the SharedPreferences) and create a Person instance out of it. It should then pass this object to the data handler which will add it (or update it if the ID is already there) to the repository of Persons. At this time you should probably consider serializing the whole repository and save it, one easy way is just to JSON it all and put it into the SharedPreferences. Don't forget that you need to load this data the first time you access the data handler so that the previously saved persons are accessible.

I would also recommend you create Interfaces for the data handling action in case you want to add new or replace the implementation to for example database operations instead.

This way you can use the PreferenceActivity for add/editing Persons. Even though I would prefer create your own UI for it.

Comment: I have multiple "Person" objects and I just want to use the look and feel of the preferences system to set each one. So each time the Activity is loaded the settings will be coming from a different "Person" - not a single one.

Think of it as preferences for a particular "Person" object.

Comment: The way the PreferenceActivity is meant to be used is to stored values that are shared throughout the App, since the App's context will determine which preferences are loaded. Therefor there would be 1 name and 1 age for the whole App. Of course it's possible to work around it, having the activity create a Person object and save it somewhere else, meaning each time it would be a new person added to the other persons. But it would be somewhat illogical to do it that way.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I don't think you are understanding my problem. I appreciate your help, but I haven't explained myself clearly. I will re-word the question to better reflect my issue.

Comment: It's a good idea to add some kind of user story to put it all in context.

Comment: Agreed. I have updated the question. Basically, I just want the UI of a preference activity and I want to hijack the load/save methods to use my POJO as the datasource.